# SHA-1 unbalanced Feistel network?

Tags: hash, cryptography, sha1

Does SHA-1 use an unbalanced or a balanced Feistel network?

For my understanding it uses an unbalanced Feistel network, because each 160-bit block gets split into five 32-bit words.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11615/why-is-an-iv-used-in-merkle-damg%c3%a5rd-transform/11617#11617 is a bit related (in that it would answer it for SHA512).  But since this is about the algorithm the crypto stackexchange is a much better fit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. This question is much better suited for [crypto.se].